# Extract string , grep IP address but exclude subnet with CIDR from text file using regex in a linux shell

Tags: regex, shell, awk, grep

I need to parse a text file which contains multiple lines of IP information but i want to extract the IP Address but exclude the subnet with CIDR using grep and a regex expression.

Sample text rows:

`Removed host entry 10.43.160.72 @10.43.160.64/26-> esjc-test-sr90p`
`Removed host entry 10.26.232.157 @10.26.232.0/22-> esjc-test-sr90p`

Desired output :

`10.43.160.72`
`10.26.232.157`

Currently im using :

`grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" test`

But this also includes the subnet information i want to avoid .

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested with GNU `grep`.

```
grep -E -o '([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\s|$)' Input_file | cut -d' ' -f1
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+$/){print $i}}}' Input_file
```

OR with OP's used regex(with little tweak in it) try following:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^(([0-9]{1,3})\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/){print $i}}}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

[Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

```
$ cut -d' ' -f4 file
10.43.160.72
10.26.232.157
```